# a typedef name may not be redeclared as a parameter[ specific tool chain ]

Tags: c, arm, typedef

I am compiling openssl with ARM specific toolchain. I am getting below error as

151
a typedef name may not be redeclared as a parameter
(http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0496c/BABDJCCI.html)

The basic openssl code is like

in base.h

```
typedef struct rsa_st RSA;
```

defines in pem.h are:

```
#define DECLARE_PEM_read_bio(name, type) \
    OPENSSL_EXPORT type *PEM_read_bio_##name(BIO *bp, type **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);

DECLARE_PEM_read_bio(RSAPublicKey, RSA)
```

Since it is used very much in openssl, this seems strange.
I didn't find any solution to fix it.

Comment: Did you try to preprocess-only the code which causes the error message?

Comment: Preprocessing the posted code (after a little cleanup of comments in wrong syntax), gives `OPENSSL_EXPORT RSA *PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(BIO *bp, RSA **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);`; which looks like it cannot causes the mentioned error message. Please double check that what you have posted is identical to what causes the error.

Comment: Although it should work, it's a bit weird to do a forward declaration where the struct tag and typedef name aren't identical. You could try `typedef struct RSA RSA;` and see if it makes any difference.